# What is the smallest element of $A:=\{k\in N:k>nx\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on Lebi's Real Analysis textbook and I am running into a bit of a challenge. I am on the section about the Archimedean property, and from what I understand it means that for any $x,y\in R$ you could find a $n\in N$ such that $nx>y$.

The next part is a proof about the set of rationals being dense in the set of real. It begins with defining the set $A:=\{k\in N:k>nx\}$ and says that it is nonempty. This makes sense, because of the Archimedean property, but I am thought that one could make a claim about the smallest element in $A$. I can see that $\inf A=nx$ so why isn't $(nx+1)$ the least element in $A$?

Comment: If it is as you described, you are right. $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ and therefore has a minimal element. That element will not be $nx+1$ since $nx$ doesn't have to be a natural number. The minimum should be $\lfloor nx+1\rfloor$ (the smallest natural number strictly greater than $nx$). Also $\text{inf} A \neq nx$ since the infimum equals the minimum if it exists.

Comment: I just checked in the book, they just call that minimum $m$, they don't make it explicit since making it explicit doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah, I think my biggest mistake was assuming nx to be a natural number. You are right that they just defined it as $m$. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, $nx$ need not be an integer at all.  Also $nx$ could be negative.  But:  If $nx < 0$ then $\inf = 0$ (assuming your text claims $0$ is a natural number.  If not then $nx < 1$ then $\inf = 1$).  If $nx$ is an integer greater than or equal to $0$ then $\inf = nx+1$.  BUt if $nx$ is a positive number but not an integer then $\inf = \lceil nx \rceil$.  You can probably combine this to make it a single statement $\inf A = \max(0, \lfloor nx+1 \rfloor$ but... actually finding this exact expression of the value is not that important and worrying about it is actually a distraction.

Comment: Oh, by the way $nx$ is not $\inf A$.  $nx$ is *a* lower bound of $A$ but it is not the greatest lower bound.

Comment: @VincentBatens "The minimum should be ⌊nx+1⌋ (the smallest natural number strictly greater than nx)"  A slight nitpick.  $\lfloor nx+1\rfloor$ is the smallest *integer* strictly greater than $nx$.    But if $nx <-1$ such an integer need not but a natural number.  If $nx < -1$ then the smallest natural number strictly larger than $nx$ is $0$.  But.... it *is* a nitpick.  You comment is otherwise spot on.

Comment: @fleablood Ah yes, I wasn't paying too much attention to the details, since in the end, all of this is just distracting from the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not correct to say that the infimum is $nx$, rather it will be $\lfloor nx\rfloor + 1$, with $\lfloor nx \rfloor$ the [floor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $nx$. This is because $A$ is a subset of the natural numbers and any such set has a least element which will also be the infimum.

Comment: Although it seems obvious now, I didn't realize that the infimum for a subset of the natural numbers also has to be the least element, thank you!

Comment: @MusicalTaco Subsets of the natural numbers are closed, so they contain all their limit points. That includes the infimum.

Comment: The next section makes the claim that infimum of $A:=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in N\}$ is 0 but the least element is 1. So is the idea "if an infimum of a subset of the natural numbers is a natural number, than it has to also be the least element"?

Comment: @MusicalTaco $\frac1n$ is not an element of the natural numbers. So any subset of the naturals numbers contains its least element which is also its infimum but that doesn't hold for the rationals or even the integers. The set $\{\frac1n : n \in N\}$ does not have a least element, but $1$ is the maximum and also the supremum.